# Cannot query based on TimeUUID in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to query the Cassandra database using SparkSQL terminal.
Query:

```
select * from keyspace.tablename 
where user_id = e3a119e0-8744-11e5-a557-e789fe3b4cc1;
```

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.88] failure: ``union'' expected but identifier e5 found

Also tried:

```
user_id= UUID.fromString(\`e3a119e0-8744-11e5-a557-e789fe3b4cc1\`)")

user_id= \'e3a119e0-8744-11e5-a557-e789fe3b4cc1\'")

token(user_id)= token(`e3a119e0-8744-11e5-a557-e789fe3b4cc1`)
```

I am not sure how can I query data on `timeuuid`.

Answer (score 1):

TimeUUIDs are not supported as a type in SparkSQL so you are only allowed to do direct string comparisons. Represent the TIMEUUID as a string

```
select * from keyspace.tablename where user_id = "e3a119e0-8744-11e5-a557-e789fe3b4cc1"
```

Comment: I have tried this too, but sparkSQL does not recognize TIMEUUID:1) val group = csc.sql("select a from keyspace.table WHERE user_id='e3a119e0-8744-11e5-a557-e789fe3b4cc1'"); 2)group.show() // This will throw error as: Cannot convert object e3a119e0-8744-11e5-a557-e789fe3b4cc1 of type class org.apache.spark.sql.types.UTF8String to java.util.UUID.

Comment: Use the HiveContext, the error may be dependent on your version make sure you are using the latest release for your available connecto

Comment: I found that this is the issue with DSE 4.8.4 and is fixed in upper versions of DSE 5.0.0 .